# Possible NetTrain[] memory leak when training in GPU

Tags: neural-networks, memory

I've just moved to Mathematica 12.0 (from 11.3) and sometimes `NetTrain[]` will fail with the following error:

```
NetTrain::gpumemex: Computation aborted: GPU memory exhausted.
```

This never happens the *first* time I call `NetTrain[]`, which makes me believe that there is some sort of memory leak. Is there a way to free up the memory of GPU, without quitting the kernel? (Because then I have to run all my preprocessing code again). I tried to call `Remove[]` on the trained network, but that didn't make any difference.

This did not happen with 11.3. Sorry that I don't have a MWE at the moment.

[image]